# Flutter how can i grant permission for notification?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, push-notification

I'm doing local push notifications. But when user doesn't grant permission, its not showing bubble for it. How can i grant access from user while that settings on the image is closed ? Thanks for help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can defined the settings like this in main

```
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
      AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
  final IOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
      IOSInitializationSettings(
    requestSoundPermission: false,
    requestBadgePermission: false,
    requestAlertPermission: false,
    onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification,
  );
  final MacOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsMacOS =
      MacOSInitializationSettings(
          requestAlertPermission: false,
          requestBadgePermission: false,
          requestSoundPermission: false);
  final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
      macOS: initializationSettingsMacOS);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
      onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
```

Then to get permission call (iOS)

```
final bool result = await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
    .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
        IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
    ?.requestPermissions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
    );
```

Adding these will pop up a page for the user to accept getting notifications. But please notice that if the user denies to give permissions then the notifications are not saved and we will not be able to force receiving a notification.